# Using a list of objects as a parameter for an odata Action

Tags: asp.net-web-api, odata

Attempting to setup an action in my odata WebAPI controller, that accepts a List of objects.

however, when I try:

```
updateSortOrder.Parameter<List<UpdateItem>>("SortOrder");
```

and pass in

```
{"SortOrder": [{"ItemProperty":"test"}]}
```

my ODataActionParameters is null.

It works if I change the parameters to accept a single UpdateItem rather than a list,
and use:

```
{"SortOrder": {"ItemProperty":"test"}}
```

or if I create a wrapper class that contains a list of UpdateItems, but I have been unable to set the parameter itself to a list.

Answer (score 4):

Use,

```
updateSortOrder.CollectionParameter<UpdateItem>("SortOrder");
```

instead.